# Script If then match between two sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, match

What I am trying to do is make this formula `=iferror(if(match($A2&F$1,arrayformula(Transpose!B$3:B&Transpose!B$1),0),"P"),"")` into a script for google sheets. Essentially the formula run in every other column after F and every row under 2 .

For example in Column H I have 
    `=iferror(if(match($A2&H$1,arrayformula(Transpose!C$3:C&Transpose!C$1),0),"P"),"")`

in Column J I have `=iferror(if(match($A2&J$1,arrayformula(Transpose!D$3:D&Transpose!D$1),0),"P"),"")` 
and so on. 
The way I have it right now has this formula pasted in every cell of every other column and as I add more data I have to adjust the formula so it takes too long. I have attached the Workbook so you can see what I am talking about. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBrg4XoeL21mXwn93XT35kgjrE5pqx9cd3xEvfojIXM/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried

```
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Transpose')
  var Ts=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZBrg4XoeL21mXwn93XT35kgjrE5pqx9cd3xEvfojIXM').getSheetByName('Attendance')
  var meeting = ss.getRange("B3:B37").getValues();
  var targetNames = Ts.getRange("A2:A37").getValues();
  var writtingRange = Ts.getRange("F2:F37").getValues();
  var updatedUser = targetNames;
  var writtingColumn = -1;
  var coolMatrix;

  for (var i = 0; i < meeting.length; i++) {
    var name = meeting[i][0]
    for (var j = 0; j < targetNames.length; j++) {
      if (targetNames[j][0] == name) {
        for (var z = 0; z < writtingRange[0].length; z++) {
          if (writtingRange[j][z] == '' && writtingColumn < 0) {
            writtingColumn = z;
            break;
          }
        }
        writtingRange[j][writtingColumn] = meeting[i][1];
        updatedUser[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  Ts.getRange("F2:F37").setValues(writtingRange);
}
```

But it gives me blanks where names match and undefined where names don't match "undefined" also I know this script would only work for one column not every other column.

Comment: Can you show the script you have tried to replicate this?

Comment: @jascanellas I have just added the script I have tried. I am not sure how much it would help

Comment: You are getting `undefined` because `writtingRange` is empty or with the value "undefined". I don't understand the third `for` loop, as it is checking the length of a column you are not writing yet. Can you explain what are you trying to compare, and what is the result you expect?

Comment: So I am new at this and I had an old script that did copy and paste but from top rows to bottom rows based on student names which is where I got this scrip, so I am not sure what the third *for* if for. My ultimate goal is as follow: I have 2 sheets Sheet1 named *Transpose*  collected  names of who is present  (data was gather form a Google form) . Example column B's name os 2/12/2020 and rows 3-8 have names of kids. Column C named 2/12/2020 has X # names under it and so on.  Sheet2  has those names in random order on column A then Column F is 2/12/2020 Column H 2/13/2020  J 2/14/2020

Comment: What I need to do is every kid that is present each day should get a "P" on the day they are present and left blank if otherwise. @Jescanellas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue with the spaces in the names of the sheet. It's because of the `=transpose(split(B2,","))`, where it splits each list separating the names by `,`. The problem is there is a space after the coma, and it messes up the comparison between names. When the name is in the first position, it doesn't have a space but it does if it's in another position of another list.

I fixed this by getting each list again and doing a [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to remove the first space of each name. Also, you should remove the first space of each name in the list of the Sheet Attendees.

```
function myfunction() {

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var transpose = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Transpose");
  var attendance = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Attendance");

  //Ranges of Transpose
  var colDates = transpose.getRange("B1:I1").getValues();
  var attendees = transpose.getRange("B2:I2").getValues();

  //Ranges of Attendance
  var eventsCol = ["F","H","J","L","N","P","R","T"]; //The dates of Transpose are different from the ones in Attendance, so I added "T" so the script doesn't broke.
  var kids = attendance.getRange("A2:A17").getValues(); //Increase this if you add more names ("Abraham Paz" was missing from this list)

  loop1:
  for (var i = 0; i < eventsCol.length; i++){ //For each column 

    var list = getIndividuals(attendees[0][i]); //Get the list of each Transpose row 2

    loop2:
    for (var x = 0; x < kids.length; x++){ //For each name in Attendance

      loop3:
      for (var y = 0; y < list.length; y++){ //Compare it with each name of the list

        if (list[y] == kids[x][0] || list[y] == " " + kids[x][0]){ //Second "or" is in case there is an space in the first position.

          attendance.getRange(eventsCol[i]+(x+2)).setValue("P");
          break loop3; //Once it finds a name it makes no sense to keep searching. Go back to the next name.

        } 

      }

    }
  }

}
//Split the list into each name, removing the first space
function getIndividuals(attendees){

  var individuals = attendees.split(",");

  for (var i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++){ 

    if (individuals[i][0] == " "){

      individuals[i][0].replace(" ", "");

    }

  }

  return individuals;
}
```

---

**RESULT**
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so so much ! @jescanellas

Comment: Would it be easy to add an *If name not found put "A"*?

Comment: I think it would be easier to set 'A' to everyone and then run the script and set the 'P's. I can take a look in a few days.

Comment: @Jascanellas Thank you ! I greatly appreciate all your help <3 You have saved me HOURS of work!